# Integrate $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{(1+x)^2}dx$ using contour integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

How to integrate this integral using contour integration?

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{(1+x)^2}dx$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use a substitution first ?

Comment: Yup. Just wanted to know how to proceed via contour integral.

Comment: Use $y = x-1$ then a key-hole contour.

Comment: Similar to this approach http://advancedintegrals.com/2017/02/15/euler-reflection-formula-proof-using-contour-integration/

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take a disk of radius $R$ centered at $1$ and remove an $r$-neighborhood of the segment $[1,R+1]$. The boundary of this consists of an almost complete circle large circle, half a small circle (radius $r$) and two segments (above and below the real segment $[1,R+1]$ and your function takes opposite signs on the two because of the square root. The contribution of a contour integral along the segments give you therefore twice the value you want and you pick up a residue at $x=-1$ as you let $R\rightarrow \infty$ and $r\rightarrow 0$.